# Android: Possible for background thread to block until UI thread finishes operation?

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread

Is it possible for a background thread to enqueue a message to the main UI thread's handler and block until that message has been serviced?

The context for this is that I would like my remote service to service each published operation off its main UI thread, instead of the threadpool thread from which it received the IPC request.

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you need.  It uses `notify()` and `wait()` with a known  object to make this method synchronous in nature.  Anything inside of `run()` will run on the UI thread and will return control to `doSomething()` once finished.  This will of course put the calling thread to sleep.

```
public void doSomething(MyObject thing) {
    String sync = "";
    class DoInBackground implements Runnable {
        MyObject thing;
        String sync;

        public DoInBackground(MyObject thing, String sync) {
            this.thing = thing;
            this.sync = sync;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (sync) {
                methodToDoSomething(thing); //does in background
                sync.notify();  // alerts previous thread to wake
            }
        }
    }

    DoInBackground down = new DoInBackground(thing, sync);
    synchronized (sync) {
        try {
            Activity activity = getFromSomewhere();
            activity.runOnUiThread(down);
            sync.wait();  //Blocks until task is completed
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("PlaylistControl", "Error in up vote", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what calling notify() on a String would do?